# lxml xpath not working if default namespace is present

Tags: python, xml, lxml, python-3.7

My org is migrating from python 2.7 to python 3.7. There is some python code that I have not written but have to be migrated. Code uses xml.xpath to parse xml.

Given that xml.xpath is not available in python 3.7. I am trying to port the code to use Xpath from lxml.etree. Intention is to keep amount of code change to minimal.

I have pasted the current implementation as well the code that I am porting it to. The ported code is not working since XML has default namespace.

Current code

```
>>> from xml import xpath
>>> from   xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> Test_XML = '<ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:ibml="http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ibmlVersion="1-56" version="4-2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005C:\\IBTIBML\\trunk\\src\\xsd\\IBML.xsd"><header><sentBy>test_value</sentBy><sendTo>test_value</sendTo><creationTimestamp>2012-06-06T08:23:20.613</creationTimestamp></header><tradeReference></tradeReference></ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest>'

>>> doc = parseString( Test_XML )
>>> ctx = xpath.Context.Context( doc, processorNss = {'ibml' : 'http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005'} )
>>> expr = xpath.Compile( '/ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest/header/sentBy' )
>>> node = expr.evaluate(ctx)
>>> node[0].childNodes[0].data
u'test_value'
>>>
```

Attempt to port it to lxml.etree. But it does not work as XML has default namespace.

```
>>> from lxml import etree as ET
>>> element = ET.fromstring( Test_XML )
>>> element.xpath( '/ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest/header/sentBy', namespaces = {'ibml' : 'http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005'} )
[]
```

However if I remove the default namespace then the xpath evaluation up works fine.
But it is not desired solution as XML creation is outside of the scope of code. Also It wont be possible to change the xpath query as that is also out side the scope of code.

```
>>> Test_XML_No_Default_NS = '<ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:ibml="http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ibmlVersion="1-56" version="4-2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005C:\\IBTIBML\\trunk\\src\\xsd\\IBML.xsd"><header><sentBy>test_value</sentBy><sendTo>test_value</sendTo><creationTimestamp>2012-06-06T08:23:20.613</creationTimestamp></header><tradeReference></tradeReference></ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest>'

>>> ee = ET.fromstring( Test_XML_No_Default_NS )
>>> ee.xpath( '/ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest/header/sentBy', namespaces = {'ibml' : 'http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005'} )
[<Element sentBy at 0x1546b058>]
>>> node = _
>>> node[0].text
'test_value'
```

Any suggestion on how I can move forward ?

Comment: *Code uses xml.xpath to parse xml*. What is xml.xpath? There are no import statements in "Current code".

Comment: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes

Comment: I found out that xml.xpath is part of the old and unmaintained PyXML package
(https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml).

Comment: @mzjn Sorry for the trouble. Edited the question and added import statement.

Comment: Anyway, I don't see a way to do what you want without changing the XPath query string. lxml requires a prefix also for the default namespace: `NSMAP = {'ibml':'http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005', 'd': 'http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2'})`. Then `element.xpath('/ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest/d:header/d:sentBy', namespaces=NSMAP)` would work.

Comment: @mzjn Initial version of code was tested in python 2.7. Now have edited to work in both python 2.7 & python 3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question directly, but try this and see if it works (maybe with modifications)

```
import lxml.etree
Test_XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:ibml="http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ibmlVersion="1-56" version="4-2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005C:\\IBTIBML\\trunk\\src\\xsd\\IBML.xsd"><header><sentBy>test_value1</sentBy><sendTo>test_value2</sendTo><creationTimestamp>2012-06-06T08:23:20.613</creationTimestamp></header><tradeReference></tradeReference></ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest>'
xml = bytes(bytearray(Test_XML, encoding='utf-8')) 
ee = etree.XML(xml)
target = ee.xpath( '//ibml:validateTradeStatusRequest', namespaces = {'ibml' : 'http://ibml.jpmorgan.com/2005'} )
print(target[0].xpath('//text()')[0])
```

Output:

> test_value1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to avoid any changes to the query string. This piece of code is used by many modules and query strings are formed by those modules, outside the scope of this code.